# How to delete a text in a table cell when a specific word is found

Tags: vba, ms-word, word-2010

In my code below, when the word isn't there, all the table contente is deleted.  How to fix it?  Text is in Cell(1,1) for multiple tables.

```
Sub DeleteText()

StartWord = "Orientation:"
For Each oTbl In ActiveDocument.Tables
Set oRng = oTbl.Range

With oRng
.Find.Execute Findtext:=StartWord & "*", MatchWildcards:=True
.MoveStart wdCharacter, 0
.MoveEndUntil vbCr
.Delete

 End With
 Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you need to add `if statement` which will check if your text is found. You will find that in the code below. However, I also improved the way you delete the whole content of cell where your text is found. My solution is better in situation when you have more lines/paragraphs/sentences in the cell.

```
Sub DeleteText_Improved()

Dim StartWord As String
Dim oTbl As Table
Dim oRng As Range

StartWord = "Mauris"

For Each oTbl In ActiveDocument.Tables
Set oRng = oTbl.Range

With oRng
.Find.Execute Findtext:=StartWord & "*", MatchWildcards:=True
If .Find.Found Then
    'how to select whole cell range
    oTbl.Cell(.Information(wdEndOfRangeRowNumber), _
            .Information(wdEndOfRangeColumnNumber)).Range.Delete

End If
End With
Next
End Sub
```

**Final remark**- your code is working only for the first occurrence of the word you search for. It will not remove other cells where the word appears.

Comment: Hi,KazJaw, thank you. It's not exactly what I wanted, but help me a lot! I need delete just the paragraph that contain the word "orientation", not every paragraph into cell(1,1).